# Laravel 5 Ajax File/Image Upload

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5

I have an issue in my laravel ajax application,

I cant upload images/files through ajax POST.

here is my code.

Ajax..

```
/*Add new catagory Event*/
$(".addbtn").click(function(){
$.ajax({
      url:'add-catagory',
      data:{
        logo:new FormData($("#upload_form")[0]),
        },
      dataType:'json',
      async:false,
      type:'post',
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      success:function(response){
        console.log(response);
      },
    });
 });
/*Add new catagory Event*/
```

Blade template ...

```
 <form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="upload_form" role="form" method="POST" action="" >
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="catagry_name">Name</label>
         <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token()}}">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="catagry_name" placeholder="Name">
        <p class="invalid">Enter Catagory Name.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="catagry_name">Logo</label>
        <input type="file" class="form-control" id="catagry_logo">
        <p class="invalid">Enter Catagory Logo.</p>
    </div>

    </form>
    </div>
    <div class="modelFootr">
      <button type="button" class="addbtn">Add</button>
      <button type="button" class="cnclbtn">Reset</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Controller ..

```
public function catadd(){
    if (Input::hasFile('logo'))
    {
       return "file present";
    }
    else{
        return "file not present";
    }
}
```

Route ..

```
 Route::post('add-catagory',['as'=>'catagory_add','uses'=>'MastersController@catadd']);
```

What is the error in my code ???

I cant get the file information in laravel controller..

How can i solve this issue...?

Comment: any ideas here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38893450/sending-pdf-file-to-server-using-ajax

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Two things to change:

**Change your js file from:**

```
 data:{
    logo:new FormData($("#upload_form")[0]),
 },
```

To:

```
 data:new FormData($("#upload_form")[0]),
```

Because you would like to send the whole form.

**In your html:**

Add a name to your file input field

```
<input type="file" class="form-control" id="catagry_logo">
```

To:

```
<input type="file" name="logo" class="form-control" id="catagry_logo">
```

Comment: Woooooooooooooow.. Thanks dude... Its working perfect.

Comment: it's say TypeError: Illegal invocation

Comment: It's say lets find the answer on google, good guy, helpful ;)

Comment: @lamzozo any ideas here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38893450/sending-pdf-file-to-server-using-ajax

Comment: @Karthiga not yet

Answer (score 1):

Check in your controller what you get when you post:

```
echo dd(Input::all());
```

Check files object in php. This in PHP:

```
$_FILES

Request::file("logo");
```

Yeah, you're not really posting any data? Is the form really posting?

Comment: What about files object in php?

Comment: @marko any ideas here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38893450/sending-pdf-file-to-server-using-ajax I don't think I'm posting any data!

Answer (score 1):

it doesn't work for me because of `dataType:'json'`. If anyone gets error just remove `dataType:'json'`.

Comment: The above post of @lamzozo was almost perfect, but it only worked when remove dataType. So, it works great.